# Angularjs include on all routes except few

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to include my header on all inner pages but not on login sign-up & one other page that appears after login.
Here is my html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div ng-if="$root.user" ng-include="'modules/partials/header.html'"></div>
        <div class="view" ui-view></div>
    </div>
```

Since on the inner the value of $rootScope.user is set it shows the header.

What should i do?

Comment: why ng-if="$root.user" is here? $scope.$root holds a reference to the $rootScope. Whu You not use ng-if="user" instead.

Comment: can u create a plunker or fiddle of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Initially keep `$rootScope.user = false`
On all those pages where you do not want to show the header, you can set `$rootScope.user = true`

Comment: $rootScope.user is set when user log in

Comment: I updated the answer to initially false and then true when user logs in.

Comment: can you make a fiddle to show your issue in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also play with multiple views:

```xml
<header ui-view="header"></header>
<div ui-view></div>
```

```js
$stateProvider

// bare abstract state, only fills the unnamed view
.state("bare", {
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    "@": {
      template: "<div ui-view></div>"
    }
  }
})

// full abstract state, fills both header view and unnamed view
.state("full", {
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    "header@": {
      template: "<h1 ng-bind='header.title'></h1>",
      controller: "HeaderController as header"
    },
    "@": {
      template: "<div ui-view></div>"
    }
  }
})

// login state, inherits from bare state
.state("login", {
  parent: "bare",
  url: "/login",
  template: "...",
  controller: "..."
})

// home state, inherits from full state
.state("home", {
  parent: "full",
  url: "/home",
  template: "...",
  controller: "..."
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dsikxeR1cg1Xl1wgufNw